# Customize bottom Navigation and android using xml

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview

I want to make my bottom navigation look li the image provided how to do that? can any one please help me

This is how my bottom Navigation code

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:elevation="@dimen/spacing_medium_10"
        app:itemActiveIndicatorStyle="@null"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_background"
        app:itemRippleColor="@null"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Here is the selector for Bottom Sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/curve_shape" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/gray_color" />

</selector>
```

And here is the curve_shape code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners
                android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
                android:topRightRadius="16dp" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```